# how to guarantee the order of iframes in window.frames

Tags: javascript, iframe

We modernize a web 1.0 web application step by step.

The old application was a frames application (3 frames - top, menu and main).
These frames were defined statically in an `frameset`.
Throughout the application the top was/is referenced by index 0 in window.frames, menu by index 1 and main by index 2.
Everything was fine.

Now we made our first change.
We redesigned the start of the application and changed from frames to iframes.
Now we dynamically create those 3 iframes in JavaScript (with `$("...");`) .

We deployed the change 2 weeks ago.

Most things work ok. Most of the time in JavaScript, the first created iframe is `window.frames[0]`, the second created `iframe` is `window.frames[1]`.

But sometimes, the iframe which is created first ends up in `window.frames[1]` and 
the iframe which is created in the command after the first ends up in 
`window.frames[0]`.

This mixes up the hole application, because - as I mentioned before - `window.frames[0]` has to be the top `iframe`.

We cannot change the references from index to id, this would be to time-consuming.

We have to - somehow - guarantee, that the "top" `iframe` is always `window.frames[0]`.

Thanks

Edit:

Thank you - Andry - for your posts.

The web application is pretty large. It startet in 2001. The tiring job would be to find all `window.frames[x]` locations, change it and hope nothing other breaks.

I would like to change as little as possible (don't change a running system).

I would be happy not to change all those references from index to id.

The best and easiest thing would be to guarantee the order of frames in the 
first place.

Comment: The old application uses "window.frames" in many places, we cannot change that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, blex. But window.frames is read only, I cannot write it.

Comment: Is it a graphic problem or logic? I mean, do you have a problem for which your iframes are swapped and the final rendered outcome is wrong, or your problem is referencing these iframes? In the latter case, your problem is identifying the correct iframe right?

Comment: It is a logic problem. Every iframe is "mapped" to a cgi program. The first iframe is mapped to a program to change customer number, the secound i mapped to the menu program.

Comment: So I guess you can access javascript API to interact with your web application, in that case my answer should be fine. Otherwise please provide more details for your scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

Before it I was creating AND assigning properties in one place:

```
 myiframe1 = $('<iframe />');
 myiframe1.attr("...", "...");
 myiframe1.attr("...", "...");

 myiframe2 = $('<iframe />');
 myiframe2.attr("...", "...");
```

Now I will change this. In the first place I will only create iframe tags.

```
iframe = $('<iframe />');
iframe.appendTo("body");
iframe = $('<iframe />');
iframe.appendTo("body");
iframe = $('<iframe />');
iframe.appendTo("body");
```

After this, when the iframes are in the window.frames array, I assign them the other attributes as needed.

```
myiframe1 = window.frames[0].frameElement;
myiframe2 = window.frames[1].frameElement;
myiframe3 = window.frames[2].frameElement;
```

So after the order of iframes is fixed in the window frames "array", I can assign the ids.

```
 myiframe1.attr("id", "top");
 myiframe1.attr("src", ".../cgi-bin/top");

 myiframe2.attr("id", "menu");
 myiframe2.attr("src", ".../cgi-bin/menu");
```

Comment: I understand your concerns about your legacy code. Nobody would like to touch old parts, however consider that `window.frames` is not standardized as reported here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames.

If you want to move your web application to a better level, you should consider changing this logic. Also this fix you made, it sound to me not reliable. I mean, since there is no standard coverage for `window.frames`, you have no guarantees about the fact that your fix will actually fix the problem as you are still relying on `frames`. This is just my advice :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We also want to modernize the old application, step by step. For now, with my solution I have to touch only a few lines of code. Tomorrow we will deploy the change and after this we will get in contact with the 2 users who are having this issue. Hopefully it will work then. I will report.

Comment: Always nice to have discussions like this. Of course I had a feeling that you were proceeding incrementally and this is a good thing to do: step by step. If you have problems post your questions, we'll all be glad to answer them :) Good luck with your renovation!

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand if your problem is the final rendered outcome (your frames get to be in the wrong position), or an identification problem (you expect the top `iframe` to be in 0 position and you reference the wrong one). So here I have two possible solutions.

### Positioning iframes

If your problem is making sure those `iframe`s are correctly positioned, then, at creation time, it should be just fine to ensure the order when generating those elements:

```
var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
// <...> Logic to add/remove attributes or style to frame1
var frame2 = document.createElement('iframe');
// <...> Logic to add/remove attributes or style to frame2
var frame3 = document.createElement('iframe');
// <...> Logic to add/remove attributes or style to frame3

// Assuming you want to add them in the body
document.body.appendChild(frame1);
document.body.appendChild(frame2);
document.body.appendChild(frame3);
```

Unsless you use some weird CSS style acting on the order of these elements (like flex), it is fine!

### Referencing iframes

Just use ids on those elements when creating them:

```
var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
frame1.id = 'f0';
var frame2 = document.createElement('iframe');
frame2.id = 'f1';
var frame3 = document.createElement('iframe');
frame3.id = 'f2';

// Assuming you want to add them in the body
document.body.appendChild(frame1);
document.body.appendChild(frame2);
document.body.appendChild(frame3);

// Helper function to retrieve your iframes
var getFrame = function(index) {
  document.getElementById('f' + index);
};
```

So you can now use:

```
var top = getFrame(0); // Since the top iframe has index 0
var middle = getFrame(1); // Since the top iframe has index 1
var bottom = getFrame(2); // Since the top iframe has index 2
```

Should be fine I hope!

Comment: So my point here is: do not rely on `window.frames` since you have no much control there. Rather use your own system.